# Переустановка mysql в ubuntu 18

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

Ubuntu 18.0.4 пытаюсь установить mysql, после неудачной настройки.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 9 948 B/3 206 kB of archives.
After this operation, 110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [9 948 B]
Fetched 9 948 B in 0s (210 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 144667 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: ну, как обычно: `$ sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Не помогает, если б помогало, я б сюда не писал

Comment: отчего ж вы привели вывод несущественной команды, и не привели вывод существенной? исправьте, пожалуйста (нажав [edit])

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под фразой "после неудачной настройки"? Неудачной настройки чего?

Comment: Ну а вычистить всё нахрен и заново поставить?

Comment: чистил)))) Буду систему переустанавливать))